# Can we Made an anchor tag autoclick in the success function of Ajax Script?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

```
Can we Made an anchor tag autoclick in the success function of Ajax Script?

Does it Possible we Click an anchor tag through Ajax Script?

if Yes then how?I am using Ajax in asp.net MVC?

This is the Viewsource of Partial View




  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  alert("Button clicked");
  $("#bt1").click(function(){
  var data2 = $('#txt2').val();
  var data1 = $('#Color').val();
  $.ajax({
  type:"Post",
  url:'/Marker/CreateMarkerjson',
  data:"Color="+ data1 + "&txt2=" + data2,
  success:function(result)
  {
  alert(result);
  $get('click').click();
  },
  error:function(result)
  {
  alert("fail");
  }
  }); 
  });
  });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  });
  </script>



  <form action="/Marker/CreateMarkerPartial" method="post">
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Fields</legend>
  <p>

 <label for="Id" id="ID">
  Id:</label>
 <input type="text" id="txt1" />

 </p>
 <p>
 <label for="CompanyName">
  CompanyName:</label>
 <input type="text" id="txt2" />


 </p>
 <p>
 <label for="Color">
  Color:</label>
 <input id="Color" name="Color" type="text" value="" />

</p>
<p>
<input type="button" id="bt1"  value="create" />


</p>
<div id="datepicker"></div>
</fieldset>
</form>
<div>
  <a href="/Marker/Index">Back to List</a>
  <a href="/Marker/AllMarkers" id="click">click</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the anchor tag declaration?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not picking anchor tags

Comment: any source where i can read these Function about

Comment: It took sometime for me to figuring out that you were using jQuery. You can find documentation at http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Also, you should put 4 space chars before pasting any source code at stackoverflow. That is why the anchor tag is not appearing on your questions. Please update the question with the 4 spaces before each line of your source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update answer. Merged the two $(document).ready functions and changed the $get('click') to $('#click'). Let's give it a try.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    alert("Button clicked");
    $("#bt1").click(function () {
      var data2 = $('#txt2').val();
      var data1 = $('#Color').val();
      $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: '/Marker/CreateMarkerjson',
        data: "Color=" + data1 + "&txt2=" + data2,
        success: function (result) {
          alert(result);
          $('#click').click();
        },
        error: function (result) {
          alert("fail");
        }
      });
    });
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  });
</script>
<form action="/Marker/CreateMarkerPartial" method="post">
<fieldset>
  <legend>Fields</legend>
  <p>
    <label for="Id" id="ID">
      Id:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txt1" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="CompanyName">
      CompanyName:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txt2" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="Color">
      Color:</label>
    <input id="Color" name="Color" type="text" value="" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" id="bt1" value="create" />
  </p>
  <div id="datepicker">
  </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
<div>
  <a href="/Marker/Index">Back to List</a> <a href="/Marker/AllMarkers" id="click">click</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It gives an error in Error Console that 

document.getElementById('stackOverflow').click(); is not a Function

any idea please tell

Comment: It gives an error in Error Console that 

document.getElementById('stackOverflow').click(); is not a Function

any idea please tell

Comment: Oh! It it seems you are trying to accomplish is to run this statement on the server side, isn't it? I was thinking you were trying to run it on the client side. May you provide an example of your code?

Comment: $.ajax({
  type:"Post",
  url:'/Marker/CreateMarkerjson',
  data:"Color="+ data1 + "&txt2=" + data2,
  success:function(result)
  {
  alert(result);
  $get('click').click();
  },
  error:function(result)
  {
  alert("fail");
  }
 }); 

I have Made an Ajax call & in success function I have done this But its not Working

Comment: First of all I think you need to provide the correct Id attribute value on your anchor tag. If you are using IE8 you can using the Developer Tools window (press F12 in your browser) to inpect the elements of your page and discover the id of your anchor. The parameter you must pass to document.getElementById or to $get is the value you set on your anchor tag id attribute. In my example, it was "stackOverflow" but your code it is another value that you, or the runtime have defined.

Comment: But the Id on bothside is click

Comment: How your anchor tag looks like? May you post its declaration here?

Comment: <a href="/Marker/AllMarkers" id="click">Click to go Back</a>

Comment: It is becoming more difficult to figure out what is going on there, than I initially thought. I still think the problem is with your id. So, is the "alert(result)" showing up? If yes, try to check what the following statement shows "alert(document.getElementById('click'))". If it undefined, the problem is the Id. Another thing is that you can have more than one html tag declared with id attribute="click".

Comment: If no alert is showing on your success function, then your call is failing.

Comment: insertion in table is done

But it is saying that

$get is not defined

Comment: and document.getElementById('click') what does it returns?

Comment: nothing

can u tell me
what this returns

click.getElementsByTagName('a');

Comment: The getElementsByTagName() method returns a NodeList of all a elements with a specified name.

Comment: click function is not shown by Intelisense

when I put $get('click').click();

Comment: May you paste the html source of your rendered page on your question, then I can try troubleshoot it here.

Comment: Now u can see the Question again

Comment: Error console of Mozilla Firefox

Comment: I've updated the answer, if it doesn't work, I don't know what else we can do. I'd also try to rename the id of my anchor or change the javascript to change from calling the click event of the anchor to window.location.assign('/Marker/Index').

Comment: I need to go now, it is 5:45 AM here. I go to work at 6:30. I'm sorry for not being able to help you more. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can fire the click handler of the anchor tag that you want clicked.

for example:

```
<a id="clickme" href="somelink.html">Click me</a>
```

now there must be an event being fired from your ajax script on the successful completion of the request. In that function do

```
document.getElementById('clickme').click();
```

Comment: Error is 
document.getElementById('clickme').click();
is not a function
in error console